# Serial monitor reading input strings, but cannot stop a while statement

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I have just learned something called 'communication protocols' in Arduino, while I was testing this code, it appears to me that every time I input a string "YELLOW_ON" while statement works perfectly fine, however after that the serial monitor input cannot receive strings anymore. after inputting the string "YELLOW_ON", I cannot input another string which is "YELLOW_OFF" may I know why that is the case?

```
#include"Display.h"
const int YELLOW_LED = 7;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(YELLOW_LED, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available())
  {
    INPUT_SERIAL();
  }
}

void INPUT_SERIAL()
{
  String INPUT_INFO = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
  Serial.println(INPUT_INFO);

  while (INPUT_INFO == "YELLOW_ON")
  {
    Display.show("ON");
    digitalWrite(YELLOW_LED, HIGH);
    delay(250);
    digitalWrite(YELLOW_LED, LOW);
    delay(250);
  }
  if (INPUT_INFO == "YELLOW_OFF")
  {
    Display.show("OFF");
    digitalWrite(YELLOW_LED, LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have your line endings set to "Both CR&NL" in the serial monitor?

Comment: @mejenko, what do you mean by set to both CR and NL, do you mind clarifying it?

Comment: In the Serial Monitor in the IDE there is a dropdown box that sets the "line endings". What is that dropdown box set to?

Comment: Aha! yes now I got it, it was set to a new line. However, when I changed it to both CR AND NL, the serial monitor receives input strings but does nothing ;/

Comment: Ok, New Line is what you want, actually. "CR and NL" will cause problems.

Comment: @Majenko , unfortunately if I put a new line it only works for one string and it stops receiving strings ;/

Comment: how could INPUT_INFO change in the while loop?

Comment: @Juraj Well spotted. Yes. `while (INPUT_INFO == "YELLOW_ON")` should really be `if (INPUT_INFO == "YELLOW_ON")`.

Comment: @Juraj, i don't know what you mean by that, but I want the while loop to be there and I somehow want to stop it, is that possible? I want a permanent blinking of LED and then stop it by inputting a string into serial monitor

Comment: @Majenko , then there were no reason for OFF. I don't know how to answer questions with wrong logic. this sketch has so many problems. some are formal like using all uppercase for a variable name, function name etc. OP should take a coding course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments:

> I want the while loop to be there and I somehow want to stop it, is
>   that possible?

=> yes - press the reset button.
When I started programming some decades ago one of the basics was NEVER use while loops.
Why? Because you might run into deadlocks like your code does. Options:

- Check inside the while for a state change/input to break the while loop (worst choice)
- Get rid of blocking code (while/delay() ) and work with if clauses (medium)
- Get rid of blocking code (while/delay() ) and implement a state machine with switch case (better)

How to get rid of delays - IDE-file-examples-2 Digital - blinkwithoutdelay